# How to align buttons below and right-aligned to a HTML list?

Tags: html, css

I have constructed a small grid using an HTML `<ul>` list and I was planning to align buttons and text below it as I have drawn in the following figure:

[image: How it should be]

I wanted to have the buttons `Select` and `Cancel` below the grid and right-aligned along the right end of the box, while the text `S-text` would also be straight below but left-aligned (and `Other` just somewhere to the right, I can do that with absolute positioning). However, I just don't know how to do this using HTML/CSS; my attempts end up looking like this:

[image: How it is now]

Can anyone explain to me how this is done? This is a very simple example but I need to learn the principle at work here. My code is as follows:

**example.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="simple_SE.css">
</head>
<body>

<table id="bigtable">

<tbody>

<ul id="blocks">
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
</ul>

<p id="stext">S-text</p>

<button id="selectbutton" type="button">Select</button>

<button id="otherbutton" type="button">Other</button>

<button id="cancelbutton" type="button">Cancel</button>

</tbody>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**simple_SE.css**:

```
#blocks { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 190px; 
}

#blocks li { 
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 0;
    padding: 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: center; 
}

#selectbutton {
    float: left;
    position:static;
}

#cancelbutton {
    float: left;
    position:static;
}

#otherbutton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The <table> and <tbody> elements appear to be unnecessary.  If you remove them the other elements should move below the grid.

Comment: If you have `<table>`, you should also have `<tr>` and `<td>` at least once.

Comment: Your HTML is entirely invalid. Correct that, and then try styling it with CSS; The only valid child of a `<tbody>` is a `<tr>` element, and the only valid children of a `<tr>` element is either a `<td>` or `<th>` element. Any other element at all must be wrapped inside of either a `<td>` or ` <th>`.

Comment: The other answers give you the code you'll need for the fix. I tried to add a better explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to HTML! Hopefully I can provide a little more current information than the layout book you are using from 1996 that advocated tables.

So apparently I can't put everything into this box, you can check out the jsFiddle I've attached to see the full layout. Here is the CSS:

```
* {
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    .container {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:185px;
    }

    .block-list {
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
    }

    .block {
        display:inline-block;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        margin:3px 3px 0 0;
        background-color:grey;
    }

    .button-container {
        text-align:right;
    }

    .button-container:after {
        clear:both;
    }

    .button-container span {
        float:left;
    }

    .other-container {
        text-align:center;
    }
```

This is far from the best way to do it, and there are some improvements that can be made (like managing the 4px space added to the blocks that are `display:inline-block`, but this should give you what you're looking for (and not even using jQuery UI).

[Here is a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/j6hop4o4/)

Comment: Thank you. I guess my basic HTML knowledge isn't exactly recent, so I have quite a bit to learn. I have two questions: i) On the jsFiddle (and when I run the code on Firefox) the "Cancel" button isn't quite right-aligned by the box above it, it sticks out a little to the right. Is it difficult technically to make it fit precisely? ii) The graphics of the box (block-list) are different and the margins are greater. Was it important to make that change to make this work, or was there some other reason you wanted to change it?

Comment: To answer your questions: 1) no, it isn't, however I replicated your existing margin ... `3px 3px 0 0`, which translates into `margin-top:3px; margin-right:3px`. if you want the button to line up, give its container `padding-right:3px` or give the cancel button a `margin-right:3px`, either will work. 2) the margins are greater because of the 4px space added to the blocks by having white-space in between `</li>` of the previous block and `<li>` of the new. Remove the white-space in the HTML, and voila ... it'll look as you wish. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is,  wrap all buttons that you want to show below your "ul" in a div and wrap "ul" and "button div" in another div forming nested elements. This will ensure div containing buttons will be after your ul. Then you can style to place the child buttons wherever you want. And you dont need ant table element in this case.

Check this code.

HTML

```
<body>
     <div>
        <ul id="blocks">
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
           <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="buttonDiv">
           <label id="stext">S-text</label>
           <button id="cancelbutton">cancel</button>
           <button id="selectbutton">Select</button>
        </div>
     </div>
     <button id="otherbutton">Other</button>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#blocks { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 190px; 
}

#blocks li { 
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 0;
    padding: 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: center; 
}
#buttonDiv {
  width : 190px;

}
#stext {
  padding : 10px;
  font-size : 20px;
}
#selectbutton {
    float: right;
    position:static;
}

#cancelbutton {
    float: right;
    position:static;
    margin-right : 8px;
}

#otherbutton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use table. I think this would help you: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/x08uevLf/)

```
.pos {position: relative;}
.clear { clear: both; }
#stext { display: inline; float: left; margin: 10px 0 0}
#blocks { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 190px; 
}

#blocks li { 
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 0;
    padding: 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: center; 
    background: red;
}

#selectbutton {
    float: left;
    position:static;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#cancelbutton {
    float: left;
    position:static;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#otherbutton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="pos">
<ul id="blocks">
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"></li>
</ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<p id="stext">S-text</p>

<button id="selectbutton" type="button">Select</button>

<button id="otherbutton" type="button">Other</button>

<button id="cancelbutton" type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding positioning is to imagine each object as a box, with each element fitting together like a puzzle. You do just that with your set of `<li>` statements. Just do that with the other elements.

[image: Boxes]

Most people do this using `<div>` tags instead of `<table>` tags. If I were re-writing your code I'd wrap the whole thing in a container and then arrange everything inside that container.

See [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=fluid%20layout%20css) for more info on fluid layouts. As a lot of other answers have provided the code you need for a quick fix, I'll stick to a more general overview. Lets take the example above.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"><!-- This is the yellow box --></div>
    <div class="box"><!-- This is the green box --></div>
    <div class="box"><!-- This is the purple box --></div>
    <div class="box"><!-- This is the red box --></div>
    <div class="box"><!-- This is the blue box --></div>
</div>
```

This code sets your structure. Then, in the CSS we can position our elements by setting a width and floating everything.

```
#container {
    width: 190px;
}
.box {
    float: left;
}
```

If you apply this to your code and add `margin:10px;` to both the `#selectbutton` and the `#cancelbutton` you'll have what you want.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain the idea at work here. Your solution looks nice but it feels ad-hoc to do this by implementing a container of width 190x, becase if I decided, for example, that the 5x4 grid had to be a little larger, then I would have to change the number 190 until the layout looked good again. Is there no way to do it in a more general fashion by defining the "Cancel" button to always end at the same horizontal location as the grid?

Comment: I thought about this more carefully and I realized that my question above doesn't make so much sense; it was me originally who defined the width of the grid to be 190px, so it makes sense that the container should also be 190px. So thanks again, I will try to make this work.

Comment: No problem. I would recommend using % widths rather than specific width for exactly the reason you mention. This allows the page to scale as needed. As for your question, remember that it's like a puzzle. If we draw a box around the Yellow, Purple, Red, and Blue boxes, then we could float the Blue box to the right and it would always line up with the edge of the Yellow box.